# En Dashes & Hyphens in Same Phrase

Tags: punctuation

Without recasting and in lieu of unsightly suspensive hyphenation, could these work? The en dash (which means "to") is used between the figures, and the hyphens are used in the compound modifier. To me, the examples below are concise and clear.

Do you agree that the examples below are 100% punctuated correctly--yes or no?

45–50-year-old men

10–20-mile radius

$45–$55-million-per-year industry

$100,000–$150,000-a-year savings

10–15-degree temperature difference

$2–$5-per-day service fees

45–75-cent-a-week raises

55–65-mph speed zone

15–20-ounce steaks

20%–40%-a-year tax increases

Comment: I think most writers *don't* include a hyphen between the numeric value and the "units" expression.

Comment: Is this what you meant (without the hyphens)?

Comment: Personally I don't see suspensive hyphenation as "unsightly"; "45- to 50-year-old men" and "10- to 20-mile radius" look just fine to me.

Comment: If we use suspensive hyphenation, which of the following looks best?

Comment: @whippoorwill: I don't know what *you* meant there. I meant that when people write [**60 70 mph speed**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%2260-70-mph+speed%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) they usually put a hyphen between the upper/lower range values, but not between the upper range and the units (in that case, **mph**).

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you cite an example?

Comment: The ones that have "X–X-a/per-unit" (and the "X–X-year-old") before the nouns look fine to me.  The ones that are just "X–X-unit" don't, as they they should be written simply "X-X unit".

Comment: @whippoorwill: If that last comment was addressed to me, the link in my preceding comment finds two written instances of the search string (Google Books treats all punctuation marks as spaces). One of the two citations uses a hyphen between the two values, the other an "em-dash" (or en-dash, I dunno). The point is *neither* of them have a second hyphen, and I think that's normal practice.

Comment: This all falls down when you're writing the stuff with a pen. Your en-dashes etc are non-identical anyway. It even becomes problematic when switching fonts (eg using blockquotes) in printed documents.

Answer (score 2):

It *works*, and it's technically unexceptionable; but I think it should be avoided. Hyphens and en-dashes are not readily distinguished on swift or casual reading, and the typographical convention of marking ranges with en-dashes rather than hyphens is not so universally followed that you can count on your readers recognizing its significance. Consequently, *##–#-xx-xx* is not an easy construction to follow.

I urge you, as a courtesy to your readers, to employ “suspensive hyphenation”—*##- to ##-xx-xxx*—however unsightly you find it. I think that few of your readers will share your aesthetic objections (I don't), and most will appreciate your consideration (I would).

Comment: If you're used to documents with top-notch typesetting, I think it'd be entirely unremarkable, but typesetting these days is something publishers like skimp on and so you're lucky to get an m-dash instead of two hyphens =\

Comment: Okay, so for the suspended hyphenation I'd do this, right?

Comment: 45- to 50-year-old men

10- to 20-mile radius

$45 million- to $55 million-per-year industry

$100,000- to $150,000-a-year savings

10- to 15-degree temperature difference

$2- to $5-per-day service fees

45- to 75-cent-a-week raises

55- to 65-mph speed zone

15- to 20-ounce steaks

20%- to 40%-a-year tax increases

Comment: You don't need to use any hyphens when what you have is a basic unit. So only *55 to 65 mph speed zone* (or *55-65 mph speed zone*), there's no reason to use a hyphen directly between numbers and units unless they are connected to yet another word (as in *5-foot-tall*) and collectively function as a single adjective.

Comment: @guifa And a publisher who cares is going to have his own house rules anyway.