# Does the punctuation work in these specified ranges?

Tags: punctuation

As a matter of style, could these pass muster to you in terms of conciseness and punctuation - yes or no? I think they are clear and uncluttered.

5-10 year olds

5-10 year old prodigies

10-15 year mortgage

1-2 inch laceration

$2-3 million a year contract

$5-10,000 per year savings

Comment: Is this not substantially the same question as *[En Dashes & Hyphens in Same Phrase](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202092)*?

Comment: @Choster Yes, she keeps asking this. There is no possible answer that will please everyone, so she needs to please herself and be content with that. Only when writing for an organization with its own official house style must one toe the line, but if that were the case, she would not be asking since the house style guide would impose its rules on her.

Comment: Researched BBC, The Telegraph and The Economist. They use 10-15 year olds, but 10-year-old (with hyphens). They also use 10-15 foot drop, but 15-foot drop (also with hyphens). So it must be 'no hyphens' with ranges and hyphens for the singular entities. Very idiosyncratic indeed - but there you have it. Weird. Makes no sense at all.